# Changing every element in vector or list by the same number

Tags: r

I have a list (that could be changed to a vector by `unlist()`) and I want to increment every number by 1.

For example, if I have `x <- list(1, 2, 3, 6, 4)`
I want to end up with a list or a vector that will be `2 3 4 7 5`.

I was thinking about using `apply` or making a function that loops through every element but I feel like that would be messy and there must be an easier way to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really see how this would be messy.  You can add 1 to every element of a list with `lapply()`.  In R, this is the standard method for applying a function over a list.

```
x <- list(1, 2, 3, 6, 4)
lapply(x, "+", 1) ## for a list result; unlist(x) + 1 for atomic result
```

Or if you are entering the International Code Golf Championships, you can use

```
Map("+", x, 1)
```

Or you can use a `for()` loop

```
for(i in seq_along(x)) x[[i]] <- x[[i]] + 1
```

Or if you have an unlisted list, you can relist it with `x` as its skeleton.

```
relist(unlist(x) + 1, x)  ## same as as.list(unlist(x) + 1) here
```

Comment: He'll like his next shot from there.

Comment: Nice use of `+` and `lapply`